# Apache Spark EC2 job not running. No space left on device

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I have been running my program multiple times on a 20 node cluster. All of a sudden every time I run the program I get the following error:

```
15/04/19 16:52:35 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 35.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 384, ip-XXX.XXX.compute.internal): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/spark/spark-local-XXX-ebd3/18/shuffle_2_35_64 (No space left on device)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(BlockObjectWriter.scala:123)
    org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(BlockObjectWriter.scala:192)
    org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(HashShuffleWriter.scala:67)
    org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(HashShuffleWriter.scala:65)
    scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleWriter.write(HashShuffleWriter.scala:65)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:178)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Checking the UI and it says there's absolutely nothing on the nodes. I have run the program maybe 15 times and only all of a sudden has this started. Why has this occurred out of the blue? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No space left on device" is a quite clear exception: That node has no space left on the mount where the spark local files are being written: `/mnt/spark/`

Solution: go to the node (or nodes) and clean that up. `rm -rf` FTW.

If jobs are breaking  before they terminate, due to manual intervention or failure, they will often leave temp data behind.

Comment: What local files are being written out? I've added in: ` conf.set("spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles", "true")` and it's working ok so far. However, one time it occurred, I literally just ran the program again and it worked fine. So, what happened to the data that was causing it to be out of space?

Comment: Also, how do I go to the nodes? I am using the spark-ec2 script.

Comment: you'd need to `ssh` into the nodes using their PEM cert  - that's not really Spark related. Tons of resources out there: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstances.html